# How to make ball drawn with Java bounce off the edges of the panel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have java code that draws a red ball inside a class that extends the JPanel class, I have a timer that is enabled by a button that updates the position of the ball with timer ctor variable elapse. I am trying to get the difference of the height of the panel and the YPOSITION where the circle is drawn if its less than 0 the the bounce ball needs to keep moving down else it should move up, my ball hits the wall and keeps hitting it. Help me debug the code that is causing that to happen.
***RightPanel class***

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RightPanel extends JPanel {
    //define the position where the circle will be drawn
    private int positionX=150;
    private int positionY=150;
    private int radius=100;//as the shape is a circle
    //override the paint method to draw the bounce ball on the second panel


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d= (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval(positionX,positionY,radius,radius);
    }
     //let's us update the position of the ball from another class
    public int getPositionY(){
    public void setPositionX(int positionX) {
        this.positionX = positionX;
    }
    public void setPositionY(int positionY){
        this.positionY=positionY;
    }
    
    public int getPositionX(){
        return this.positionX;
    }
   
        return this.positionY;
    }
}
```

The logic in the timer class below is the one I need help with
***GameInterface class***

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GameInterface extends JFrame {
    //declare a Timer object to start the movement
    Graphics ctx;
    RightPanel rightpanel;
    private int height;
    //declare a timer to start moving the ball
    Timer mytimer= new Timer(50, new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //check this and keep moving the ball down
            if(rightpanel.getPositionY()- rightpanel.getHeight()<0){

                rightpanel.setPositionY(rightpanel.getPositionY()+5);
                rightpanel.paint(rightpanel.getGraphics());
            }else{

            //move the ball up
                rightpanel.setPositionY(rightpanel.getPositionY()-5);
                rightpanel.paint(rightpanel.getGraphics());
            }


        }
    });
    public GameInterface(){
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        height=this.getHeight();
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Bounce Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        //define a new JSplitPane and use it to add two JPanels
        JPanel leftpanel= new JPanel();
        //add buttons to the left panel programatically
        JButton up= new JButton("Move up");
        //set the event listeners for the buttons
        up.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //start he timer
                mytimer.start();


            }
        });
        JButton down = new JButton("Move down");
        down.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //move my ball down
                rightpanel.setPositionX(rightpanel.getPositionX());
                rightpanel.setPositionY(rightpanel.getPositionY()+5);
                rightpanel.paint(rightpanel.getGraphics());

            }
        });
        leftpanel.add(up);
        leftpanel.add(down);
        rightpanel= new RightPanel();
        JSplitPane splitpane= new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,leftpanel,rightpanel);
        this.add(splitpane);
        setVisible(true);
        ctx=this.getGraphics();

    }
}
```

Comment: `rightpanel.paint(rightpanel.getGraphics());` ... nope, see [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)

Comment: I just need help with making the ball detect the jpanel wall, I will replace that line later

Comment: You have problems, a `JPanel` already has a concept of location and size, but you've added in your own - it's kind of making a mess

Comment: I have an object drawn inside the JPanel the getters and setters are for the object drawn, I tried to get the difference between the height of the panel and the height of the ball and get difference

Comment: I ran your code. When the ball reaches maximum depth the "move up" button fails to move it up. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes it should start moving in the opposite direction

Comment: ok! Got ya problem!

Comment: @TechGeek And now you component has two sets of coordinates - better to seperate those concepts (IHMO)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, why did you delete that, its what I needed

Comment: If you put the moving up logic in the action listener of the "up" button and remove the line "mytimer.start()" the buttons will perform all the actions as per your logic perfectly, 
What do you want to achieve using the abstract action my timer?

Comment: I want to move it without a button, the buttons are for starting the timers

Comment: @TechGeek Because it wasn't exactly what you needed ;)

Comment: So move up should keep moving the ball upwards continuously and the move  down button  will keep moving the ball downwards? Is that what is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is, when you "drop" the ball, you need to determine the direction of movement that the ball should move in.  When the `timer` ticks, it will apply that direction of movement until it either reaches the bottom, at which time the delta is reversed, or it reaches the top.

The important part here is, all the state the `timer` needs should be determined before the `timer` is started and not calculated within the `timer` itself, as the state it needs is no longer relevant.

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Ball ball = new Ball(20);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane(ball));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Ball {
        private Point location;
        private Dimension size;
        private Shape shape;

        public Ball(int radius) {
            location = new Point(0, 0);
            size = new Dimension(radius * 2, radius * 2);
            shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        }

        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return new Rectangle(location, size);
        }

        public void setLocation(Point p) {
            location = new Point(p);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.translate(location.x, location.y);
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class SurfacePane extends JPanel {

        private Ball ball;
        private Timer timer;
        private int yDelta;

        public SurfacePane(Ball ball) {
            this.ball = ball;
            this.ball.setLocation(new Point(200 - (ball.getBounds().width / 2), 0));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            ball.paint(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void moveBallDown() {
            Rectangle bounds = ball.getBounds();
            Dimension size = ball.size;
            Point location = bounds.getLocation();
            location.y += size.height;
            if (location.y + size.height > getHeight()) {
                location.y = getHeight() - size.height;
            }
            ball.setLocation(location);
            repaint();
        }

        public void dropBall() {
            if (timer != null) {
                return;
            }
            Rectangle bounds = ball.getBounds();
            Dimension size = ball.size;
            Point location = bounds.getLocation();
            if (location.y + size.height > getHeight()) {
                yDelta = -1;
            } else {
                yDelta = 1;
            }

            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Rectangle bounds = ball.getBounds();
                    Dimension size = ball.size;
                    Point location = bounds.getLocation();
                    location.y += yDelta;
                    if (location.y < 0) {
                        location.y = 0;
                        yDelta = 0;
                        timer.stop();
                        timer = null;
                    } else if (location.y + size.height > getHeight()) {
                        location.y = getHeight() - size.height;
                        yDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    ball.setLocation(location);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private Ball ball;
        private SurfacePane surfacePane;

        public MainPane(Ball ball) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.ball = ball;
            surfacePane = new SurfacePane(ball);
            add(surfacePane);

            JPanel actionPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton up = new JButton("Up");
            JButton down = new JButton("Down");

            actionPane.add(up);
            actionPane.add(down);

            add(actionPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            up.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    surfacePane.dropBall();
                }
            });
            down.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    surfacePane.moveBallDown();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Am going to study how this code works for the whole week. Thank You so much, I want to be a professional java game programmer some day

Comment: Compile time error in `SurfacePane.java`, `ball.size` is private

Comment: Yes, `ball` is `private`

Comment: How do I fix the error?

Comment: Your answer needs a getter for dimension

Comment: What is the difference between `SurfacePane` and `MainPane`?

Comment: *"Your answer needs a getter for dimension"* - not really, you get both the size and position via `Ball#getBounds`

Comment: *"What is the difference between SurfacePane and MainPane?"* - `SurfacePane` is the area within which the ball can move, the `MainPane` is the container which contains both the `SurfacePane` and buttons and acts as a controller between them

Comment: Good, commenting could help a lot, multiline comments before each class definition on what the class does for future visitors